# HP Array P410, HDD changed, but still predict to fail soon

Tags: raid, hp

On HP Proliant DL G6, one disk in RAID 1 on P410 array broken. It was HP EG0300FBDBR. I changed it on compatible HP model - HP EG0300FAWHV. (both 300 Gb, 10K)

But HP Array Configuration Utility still show me - that new HP EG0300FAWHV - 300 GB 2-Port SAS Drive at Port 1I : Box 1 : Bay 0 is predicted to fail soon.

New disk in server blinking green - is like "The drive is rebuilding, erasing, or it is part of an array that is undergoing capacity expansion or stripe migration."

But two days gone and status didn't change.

In RIS Event Log, last info:

*> Event 123 2016-02-08 11:56:54 Hot Plug Physical Drive Change Removed.

> Physical drive number: 0x09. Configured drive flag: 1. Spare drive
>   flag: 0. Big drive: 0x00000009. Enclosure Box: 00. Bay: 00  Event 124
>   2016-02-08 12:16:57 Hot Plug Physical Drive Change Inserted. Physical
>   drive number: 0x09. Configured drive flag: 1. Spare drive flag: 0. Big
>   drive: 0x00000009. Enclosure Box: 00. Bay: 00  Event 125 2016-02-08
>   12:16:57 Logical Drive Status State change. State change, logical
>   drive 0x0000. Previous logical drive state (0x03): Logical drive is
>   degraded. New logical drive state (0x04): Logical drive is ready for
>   recovery operation. Spare status (0x00): No spare configured  Event
>   126 2016-02-08 12:16:57 Logical Drive Status State change. State
>   change, logical drive 0x0000. Previous logical drive state (0x04):
>   Logical drive is ready for recovery operation. New logical drive state
>   (0x05): Logical drive is currently recovering. Spare status (0x00): No
>   spare configured  Event 127 2016-02-08 12:51:51 Logical Drive Status
>   State change. State change, logical drive 0x0000. Previous logical
>   drive state (0x05): Logical drive is currently recovering. New logical
>   drive state (0x00): Logical drive OK. Spare status (0x00): No spare
>   configured  Event 128 2016-02-09 03:23:22 Logical Drive Surface
>   Analysis Surface Analysis pass information. Block count: 00000000.
>   Drive No: 00. Starting Address: 00000848:00000000.*

I attached ADU report and screen.

Is it mean that new disk still recovering? But why its status as "predict to fail" and why so long for recovering? Why HP utility didn't mark it as rebuilding?

Report ADU: https://www.dropbox.com/s/70ucdsiafzdwvfr/ADUReport.zip?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the replacement drive from?

If it was a spare or used disk, there's a chance that the drive is also going to fail or enter pre-failure mode. Sometimes parts sent from HP repair are mis-picked.

Can you show the output of the HPSSACLI utility?

`ctrl all show config` and `ctrl all show config detail`

Comment: Hello ewwhite, this disk from other unused server. He worked normally, was part of other RAID. Please, see report from HPSSACLI: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jml43anepzhqyq5/HPSSACLI.txt?dl=0

Comment: I am embarrassed that the green light on the drive is still flashing, and officially from HP, I can not pull it out at the time of this unfinished operations